# Iterated tensor product of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Considering a ring $R$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, is there anything known about the sequence
$$
R, \:\: 
R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R, \:\:
R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R, \:\:
...
$$
? I am especially interested in conditions implying that (or consequences arising from the fact that) $R^{\otimes k}$ and $R^{\otimes k+1}$ are isomorphic (or even just Morita equivalent).

Any pointer in the literature would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!